# Google Maps Overlay Android

Tags: java, android, overlay, draw

I would draw a resizable touchable rectangle on map of Google in my app Android. The use of OverLay on the map is correct? 
Who can help me?

I would a sample code to add resizable object in a google maps.
Thanks.

Comment: and what is your issue??

Comment: I would a sample code to add resizable object in a google maps